# FileNotFoundException. Works and doesn't work at the same time?

Tags: java, jar, getresource

I have the following code in a static class called Methods that is archived in a jar:

```
System.out.println(Methods.class.getResource("tagdict.txt")); // 1
URL test = Methods.class.getResource("tagdict.txt");          // 2
System.out.println(test.getPath());                           // 3
TagDictionary dict = new POSDictionary(test.getPath());       // 4
```

The first `System.out` (1) says:

```
rsrc:de/fhg/scai/bio/harsha/classificationworkflow/tagdict.txt
```

The second `System.out` (2) says:

```
de/fhg/scai/bio/harsha/classificationworkflow/tagdict.txt
```

Line 4 throws a

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: de/fhg/scai/bio/harsha/classificationworkflow/tagdict.txt (No such file or directory)
```

The file `tagdict.txt` is placed in the same package as the `Method.class`, which is `de/fhg/scai/bio/harsha/classificationworkflow`.

I do not understand why line 4 throws a `FileNotFoundException` even though the file was found already inside the jar.

Comment: It would help having the code for `POSDictionary`'s constructor, since the exception is thrown there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 3 just prints out the path component of the URL returned by `getResource`. It doesn't actually check if that path represents a real file on disk.

It looks like the `POSDictionary` constructor is trying to create a `File` using the path string passed to it, and this path doesn't actually represent an on-disk file, therefore throwing the exception.

> I do not understand why line 4 throws a FileNotFoundException even though the file was found already inside the jar.

Because if the resource is in a JAR, then it's not a file. Such resources can only be accessed by opening input streams directly from the `URL` object, or by using `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `getResource()`. They can't be accessed using `java.io.File`, since they're not actual disk files.